# How to increase output rows in Resource Graph Query in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-resource-graph

I am using Resource Graph Powershell module to query all the recent change details in my Subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes?tabs=azure-powershell

But though there are many changes happened, the query is returning at max 100 at a time. So is there a way to get the complete records?

Is there a way to get all available records from Resource Graph module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/how-to/get-resource-changes?tabs=azure-powershell):

```
$count= Search-AzGraph -Query 'resourcechanges | project properties.changeAttributes.timestamp, properties.changeType, properties.targetResourceId, properties.targetResourceType, properties.changes' -First 1000
 $count | Measure-Object
```

[image]

So you need to use `-First`  Paramter

Or you can use the query directly in Azure Resource graph Explorer as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can't we get more than 1000 from powershell?

Comment: Yes we can get, you can use your required number and you can use Resource graph explorer as given in answer as alternative.

Comment: Yes, since I am new, unable to upvote it.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you.